# Clear browser cache, cookies history programatically in android

Tags: android, performance, cookies, session-cookies, browser-history

I am looking to create an app for my phone which helps me to remove unwanted data temp files browser history.
 Like [Ccleaner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ccleaner) does the same job for Windows PC.

so I want to make sure is it possible ? To clear Cookie and all browser stuff programatically.
If yes then please provide me any kind of help.

Comment: does it degrade phone's performance? cookies and history? where did you read that? please link it.

Comment: @SergeyBenner edited my question please check! is it possible?

Comment: well to clear your browser cache is easy Settings->Apps-> select your browser or Internet icon there you can do "clear data" or "clear cache". Of course it depends on your browser. There's no such thing like temp files which would affect your performance. Remember it's not a disk with spindels and fragmented files. Here's a link bout file fragmentation in android http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-market/QR9fDjrXIic .  Read this link too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774161/programmatically-clear-browser-cache-history