# Android :any other way to clear browser's cache programmatically

Tags: android, browser

can we clear browser history programmatically,because when open it again previous page opened already

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774161/programmatically-clear-browser-cache-history

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774161/programmatically-clear-browser-cache-history. See the accepted answer

Comment: I have tried these                  Browser.clearHistory(getContentResolver()); Browser.clearSearches(getContentResolver());   but not getting success