# How to clear browser cache in android

Tags: android, caching, browser

I am developing an application, in which user can add URL to be blocked, means those URL can not be opened in browse. I add a URL block observer for this purpose.

```
context.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, true, this);
```

it is working fine, when blocked URL is opened in browser, I redirect user to www.google.com; but when back button of browser is pressed, that observer is not called and blocked website also get opened. So any way to clear cache files of browser, so that on back press that website could not be opened or any other way to handle this situation.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774161/programmatically-clear-browser-cache-history. check the answer by commonsware

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have checked above link, clear history and searches not fulfill my requirement, as when back button is clicked, blocked website opened from cache.

Any other way to block a specific URL to get opened in Browser.

Comment: pointed to be noted is clearing browser cache is a bad idea