# How to clear Browser Cache?

Tags: java, android, caching

I have an application in which I want to include a button for clearing all the browsers cache including default browser, or is it possible to clear cache of all the applications instead (via deleting the folders)?

How can this be achieved via button click?

Comment: The question has been answered in previous thread. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6898278/1129468) out!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3774524/3264399

Comment: no its not possible. Because it is private data of browser so you can not remove from your application.

Comment: ok is there a way to clear the cache of my OWN app? (not disable, just clear on button click).

Answer (score 0):

There's **no way** a browser will let you clear its cache. It would be a huge security issue if that were possible. This could be very easily abused - the minute a browser supports such a "feature" will be the minute I uninstall it from my computer.

What you *can* do is to tell it not to cache your page, by sending the appropriate headers or using these meta tags:

```
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
```

Comment: As the question says, i don't want to clear my own application's cache, i want to clear other app's cache. and it is possible!!